# how to add hours and minutes using canonical functions in linq

Tags: linq, entity-functions

My linq query now,

```
 return _db.Details
           .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Master.Id.Value == nId && 
                                c.Id == c.Master.Id && 
                                c.Alert.Va <= c.Va && 
                                DateTimeNowc.ValidityTill <= (EntityFunctions.AddHours(DateTime.UtcNow,5) &&
                                EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(DateTime.UtcNow,30)));
```

ERROR:

```
DateTime? EntityFunctions.Addminutes(DateTime?timevalue, int? addvalue) (+2 overload(s))
```

`Invokes the canonical Add Minutes function. For Information about the canonical  AddMinutes function, see Date and Time canonical Functions(Entity SQL).`

Here I get line error[image]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot my telescope in my other pants. It looks really stupid if I squint at my display from 5 cm afar. Could you please post the error as text?

Comment: That's not the error message. That's documentation info.

Comment: ok. how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTimeNowc.ValidityTill <= (EntityFunctions.AddHours(DateTime.UtcNow, 5) &&
EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(DateTime.UtcNow, 30)));
```

You're trying to perform `&&` on two `DateTime` instances. That's not gonna work.

You should place one method call within another:

```
EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(EntityFunctions.AddHours(DateTime.UtcNow, 5), 30));
```

Comment: The thought to nest those methods did not occur to me even once, but I like it

Comment: i want to add hours 5 and minutes 30.. for this it will work?

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison syntax is wrong. If you try to compare if the time is <= 5hours 30 minutes, try to use just AddMinutes().

```
//5*60 minutes + 30 minutes
DateTimeNowc.ValidityTill <= EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(DateTime.UtcNow,330)));
```